# basic security ubntu 12.04 LAMP server quesrions

Tags: 12.04, server, security, lamp

I have a few questions about security on my ubntu 12.04 LAMP server (newbie)

**This is what I´ve done so far:**

Install and configure Firewall - ufw

Secure shared memory - fstab

SSH - Disable root login and change port / adding ssh-key

Protect su by limiting access only to admin group

Harden network with sysctl settings

Disable Open DNS Recursion and Remove Version Info  - Bind9 DNS

Prevent IP Spoofing

Harden PHP for security

Restrict Apache Information Leakage

Install and configure Apache application firewall - ModSecurity

Protect from DDOS (Denial of Service) attacks with ModEvasive

Scan logs and ban suspicious hosts - DenyHosts and Fail2Ban

Intrusion Detection - PSAD

Check for RootKits - RKHunter and CHKRootKit

Scan open Ports - Nmap

Analyse system LOG files - LogWatch

SELinux - Apparmor

Audit your system security - Tiger

**--------------------------------**

I am also using Cloudflare which has some security features out of the box.

But should I install some sort of antivirus on my server?

(I only have outgoing email, eg users register on my site and gets a email link sent)
So I am blocking all INCOMMING emails to the server by loopback-only.

Should I block ping-requests to my site?

Or is it not a problem letting people ping my site? **ping mysite.com ...**

Off-topic, my server seems to do a reboot on its own every sunday morning 7am.
I havent started this my self with cron-jobs or so, but is there a way to disable it from doing self-reboot every sunday morning? Mostly coz some settings gets lost after a self-reboot has been done.

Lastly, I am running a cron-job to do a run a function by calling:

```
mysite.com/some-cron-job?secretKey=8934958398457
```

Is it safe to use this method `?secretKey=8934958398457` then using php to check "secretKey" value and then run the `cron-job` if its equal to "`8934958398457`"

Is there anything else I should do in order to make my server more secure?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Could you instead ask 1 question per post? Also, please demonstrate what is your final goal and how you plan to achieve it. Include what have you tried and what were the results, with what are you having troubles, etc. Always focussing in 1 problem at time/post.

Comment: Sorry my first time posting here, but I will keep that in mind until next time.

Comment: No, please [edit] the post now. Preferably in tone with the answer below. Also, if it solved the question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just say that this system is secure enough to comply with HIPAA, so yeah, you are doing all right as far as security goes.

You shouldn't need antivirus software. The OS is secure enough that nothing is going to be installed unless you tell it to be installed.

Ubuntu does not reboot itself by default, so something must have changed that causes the reboot every week. I would look in the files in /var/log (where log files are kept) to see if you can figure out what application is calling the reboot. Whatever it is must have pretty high permissions to cause a reboot.

About the secret key script: That should be ok as long as the job doesn't do anything that could cause damage or security issues. The odds of someone randomly hitting that URL is small, but you should still make sure that the script that gets invoked doesn't clear out your filesystem or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had to double check since this is my first time using ubuntu lamp,
The script being called is just a php/mysql function, its just deleting old posts.

Comment: No problem, dude. Hope this helps